# Add customer, assign data to user fields?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have followed the installation of Cashier, also running `php artisan cashier:table users` to add the stripe columns to my user table. Now, when I receive a token, and add the user as a new stripe customer, like this:

```
$user->subscription()->createStripeCustomer($data['stripeToken']);
```

I'd expect theese fields to get auto filled:

[image]

But they do not. They are simply "null" even after adding the user as a stripe client. Why?